# jCache providers features

Tags: hazelcast, ehcache, infinispan, jcache

So i'm going to use jCache implementation for my J2EE application java 8 and i want to know what is the difference between all the providers and all its features.

- Hazecast
- ehcache
- infinispan

can anyone help me to choose one of them ( in terms of cluster support, easy to use, performance ...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JCache is a specification, so that all implementations behave in the same way regarding the caching features.

However, a key differentiator to evaluate the products is whether you want the cache to be distributed or not. The Open Source version of Hazelcast is distributed, this is not the case for EhCache.

Disclaimer: I work for Hazelcast.